# Unable to find Coq library: `Error: Unable to locate library Floats.`

Tags: coq

This might be a dumb question, but when I try to import `Coq.Floats.Floats`, it doesn't work.

I've tried

```
Require Import Floats.
```

and

```
Require Import Coq.Floats.Floats.
```

to no avail.

Other standard libraries, like

```
Require Import Coq.Arith.Arith.
Require Import Coq.omega.Omega.
```

work fine.

Using coqc -v `8.6` with Emacs ProofGeneral if that makes any difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Coq 8.6 is too old. The Floats module was introduced in Coq 8.11.

Source: [Coq Changelog](https://coq.inria.fr/distrib/current/refman/changes.html#id283).

Comment: Well, turns out it _was_ a stupid question. Thank you.